Protocol delegate from custom UI button has unwanted effect
I have been trying to create a protocol and delegate between custom UI button and parent-child view controller. Briefly, I have a parent view controller, a child view controller, and a custom UI button. Custom UI button and child VC are under parent VC. I created a protocol delegate for custom UI button.
I want to change child VC's view frame origin with a tap on custom UI button. I also want to change the image of custom UI button when the button is tapped. However, when I try to change the image of custom UI button and also call delegate method, child VC view first update the child VC view frame position as in update view method. But later it resets frame position to its first position. Here is the sample code:
Parent View Controller
class ParentViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let childVC: ChildViewController = {
        let childVC = ChildViewController()
        childVC.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return childVC
    }()
    
    let customButton: CustomUIButton = {
        let button = CustomUIButton(frame: .zero)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return button
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        setupCustomButton()
        setupChildVC()
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        applyConstraints()
    }
    
    private func setupCustomButton() {
        view.addSubview(customButton)
        customButton.delegate = self
    }
    
    private func setupChildVC() {
        addChild(childVC)
        view.addSubview(childVC.view)
        childVC.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
    
    private func applyConstraints() {
        
        let childVCConstraints = [
            childVC.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            childVC.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            childVC.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 65),
            childVC.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -200)
        ]
        
        let customButtonConstraints = [
            customButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            customButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -50),
            customButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70),
            customButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70)
        ]
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(childVCConstraints)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(customButtonConstraints)
        
    }

    
}

extension ParentViewController: CustomUIButtonDelegate {
    func customUIButtonDidTap() {
        self.childVC.updateView()
    }
    
    
}

Child View Controller
class ChildViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var isHidden: Bool = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        

    }
    
    func updateView() {
        if isHidden {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                self.view.frame.origin.y -= 200
                self.isHidden = false
            }
        } else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                self.view.frame.origin.y += 200
                self.isHidden = true
            }
        }
    }
}

Custom UI Button
protocol CustomUIButtonDelegate: AnyObject {
    func customUIButtonDidTap()
}

class CustomUIButton: UIButton {

    weak var delegate: CustomUIButtonDelegate?
    
    var isDoing: Bool = false
    
    let image1: UIImage = {
        let image = UIImage(systemName: "chevron.right") ?? UIImage()
        return image
    }()
    
    let image2: UIImage = {
        let image = UIImage(systemName: "chevron.left") ?? UIImage()
        return image
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setTitle("", for: .normal)
        backgroundColor = .systemRed
        layer.cornerRadius = 35
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.systemCyan.cgColor
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        
        addTarget(self, action: #selector(didButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    
    @objc func didButtonTapped() {
        
        self.isDoing = !isDoing
        self.setImage(isDoing ? image1 : image2 , for: .normal)
        
        delegate?.customUIButtonDidTap()
        
    }
}

If I dont change the image of custom UI button in the delegate method, it works without resetting frame position to its first position. I am not sure why setting image of button has this effect.
Custom UI Button target without updating image of custom button
@objc func didButtonTapped() {
        
//        self.isDoing = !isDoing
//        self.setImage(isDoing ? image1 : image2 , for: .normal)

     delegate?.customUIButtonDidTap()
        
}


What "unwanted effect" are you talking about? I don't see you describing it in the question.

Also, please remove all unrelated code from the question.

Thank you for your comments, I will add a video to show the problem if the description is still not clear.

tip: when you want to handle the "commands" (aka user intents, like button clicks, etc.) originating from a view in the child view controller in the parent view controller, you better off using a closure variable like var customUIButtonDidTap: () -> Void  declared in the Child View Controller and setup by the Parent View Controller during the setup phase - instead of using protocols.

In the sample code, you did not show, how you embed the child view controller into the parent view controller. From experience, this is error prone. You might want to show this code, too.

You have set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false which means you must add constraints to control the position of your views. When using constraints any changes you make to frame will be overridden on the next layout pass as the constraints are used to determine the layout. If you want to change the position you need to change the constraints. You can animate the change to constraints.

@CouchDeveloper Thank you for the tip! I know the alternative using closure, but I want to understand this behavior for the delegate method. I show all the sample codes now in case you want to try.

@Paulw11 Thank you for the comment. I also think about changing the frame with constraints but currently, I want to change the frame from child VC, not from the parent VC. Besides if I don't change the image of custom button, the update from child VC works. I am curious about the reason why update doesn't work along with the setting image of custom button

I solved it by adding a container view to child VC and updating its frame instead of child VC's root view. Here is the code if anyone wants to check.
Updated child VC
class ChildViewController: UIViewController {

var isHidden: Bool = false

private var containerView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.addSubview(containerView)
    
    let containerViewConstraints = [
        containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
        containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
        containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
    ]
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(containerViewConstraints)
}

func updateView() {
    if isHidden {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.containerView.frame.origin.y -= 200
            self.isHidden = false
        }
    } else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.containerView.frame.origin.y += 200
            self.isHidden = true
        }
    }
}

}

Couple issues with your original code...

viewDidLayoutSubviews() is called many times -- every time any UI element in the view is changed

you're mixing constraints with explicit .frame modifications. When you set the button's image, auto-layout "re-applies" the constraints that you've setup.


If your use of a "container" view is working (and you've fully tested it), you could stick with that approach.
Otherwise, you should either:

NOT use constraints on your childVC.view and instead set its .frame as needed, or
define a constraint property and update its .constant property

Here's your code, modified to use the second approach:
///**Parent View Controller**

class ParentViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let childVC: ChildViewController = {
        let childVC = ChildViewController()
        childVC.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return childVC
    }()
    
    let customButton: CustomUIButton = {
        let button = CustomUIButton(frame: .zero)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return button
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        setupCustomButton()
        setupChildVC()
        applyConstraints()
    }
    
    private func setupCustomButton() {
        view.addSubview(customButton)
        customButton.delegate = self
    }
    
    private func setupChildVC() {
        addChild(childVC)
        view.addSubview(childVC.view)
        childVC.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
    
    private func applyConstraints() {

        // we start with the childVC.view visible
        let childBottom: NSLayoutConstraint = childVC.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -200.0)

        // assign childVC's bottomConstraint
        childVC.bottomConstraint = childBottom

        let childVCConstraints = [
            childVC.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            childVC.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            childVC.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 65),
            //childVC.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -200)
            childBottom,
        ]
        
        let customButtonConstraints = [
            customButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            customButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -50),
            customButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70),
            customButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70)
        ]
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(childVCConstraints)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(customButtonConstraints)
    }
    
    
}

extension ParentViewController: CustomUIButtonDelegate {
    func customUIButtonDidTap() {
        self.childVC.updateView()
    }
    
    
}

///**Child View Controller**

class ChildViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
    }
    
    func updateView() {
        guard let bc = bottomConstraint,
              let sv = self.view.superview
        else {
            fatalError("Invalid setup!")
        }
        
        // if the .constant is 65,
        //  self.view is "down and out of view" (hidden)
        if bc.constant == 65.0 {
            bc.constant = -200.0
        } else {
            bc.constant = 65.0
        }
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            sv.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}

///**Custom UI Button**

protocol CustomUIButtonDelegate: AnyObject {
    func customUIButtonDidTap()
}

class CustomUIButton: UIButton {
    
    weak var delegate: CustomUIButtonDelegate?
    
    var isDoing: Bool = false
    
    let image1: UIImage = {
        let image = UIImage(systemName: "chevron.right") ?? UIImage()
        return image
    }()
    
    let image2: UIImage = {
        let image = UIImage(systemName: "chevron.left") ?? UIImage()
        return image
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setTitle("", for: .normal)
        backgroundColor = .systemRed
        layer.cornerRadius = 35
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.systemCyan.cgColor
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        
        addTarget(self, action: #selector(didButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    @objc func didButtonTapped() {
        
        self.isDoing = !isDoing
        self.setImage(isDoing ? image1 : image2 , for: .normal)
        
        delegate?.customUIButtonDidTap()
        
    }
}


Thank you for your alternative way. I also tried to apply your approach but there were some problem with the constraint since child VC view's bottom constraint constant is dynamic. I also checked whether viewDidLayoutSubviews() calls many times when I use the container view approach, but it doesn't. So I will stick with this approach. Thanks for your time!
